# Drawflow: How can I make the nodes sizeable?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a small Diagram and Im using Drawflow plugin for that.

How can I make the nodes sizeable in the Drawflow plugin?

Comment: In case someone wonders where the plugin is: https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow